# How to return a value of a JSON string?

Tags: python, json

Write a function named "get" that takes a JSON formatted string as a parameter in the format of an object with keys "x" and "y" each mapping to an array of integers. Return the y-value at x == 11.

Input: `['{"x": [-5, 4, 3, 19, 11], "y": [-5, 7, -11, 6, -3]}']`

Expected Output: `-3`

```
import json
def get(lista):
    load = json.loads(lista)
    if load['x'] == 11:
        return load['y']
```

I am returning a value of 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look into the enumerate function and iterate over your load object.

Comment: Why did you expect an output of -3? I'd expect a TypeError or, if `lista` is the actual JSON string (which makes that a bad name for the parameter), `[-5, 7, -11, 6, -3]`.

Comment: JSON decoding aside, it looks like you need to iterate over two lists in parallel, returning the element in the `y` list when you reach the element `11` in the `x` list. It's not clear, though what `lista` actually is; it looks like it is actually a list that contains a single string that happens to be a JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load['x']` is a list; it can never be equal to `11`. You need to loop over its elements and check if an *element* is `11`. You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to gain access to the index as you loop:

```
def get(lista):
    load = json.loads(lista)
    for index, element in enumerate(load['x']):
        if element == 11:
            return load['y'][index]

print(get('{"x": [-5, 4, 3, 19, 11], "y": [-5, 7, -11, 6, -3]}'))
# -3
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the keyword 'enumerate'?

Comment: @Anonymous it gives you access to the index of the element in the list as you're iterating.